# create a string from first 2 elements in dataframe and add to new column in R

Tags: r

I think this is fairly simple, say I have a data frame

```
> vadata 
    va1 va2
1   a   c
2   b   d
```

I want to create a new column va3 = "a-c" and "b-d" for all rows in vadata and append to vadata?

vadata is of type dataframe.

Is there an easy to way do this in r?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `paste` to do that.

```
vadata$va3 <- paste(vadata$va1,vadata$va2,sep="-")
```

Comment: thanks, what if I had say 30 columns each for which I wanted to create va1-va(col#) and append to the end of the data.frame, is there a way to iterate over this, perhaps using the name() function to get a list of the column headings?  Sorry very new to R thanks

Comment: You could use `apply` and `paste`: `vadata$vaN <- apply(vadata, 1, function(x) paste(x,collapse="-"))`

Comment: What I was looking for was creating 30 columns per each pair va1-va(col#) and appending it to the end of the table.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly you have a data frame with 30 columns and you want to append to this column 1+2 ,2+3, 3+4.. to add 15 new columns?

Comment: yes or basically (1-2,1-3,1-4,1-5,...,1-30) so 29 columns to add technically

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **mutate()** from **dplyr** library.

```
library(dplyr)
vadata = vadata %>% mutate(va3 = paste(va1,va2, sep='-'))
vadata

  va1 va2 va3
1   a   c a-c
2   b   d b-d
```

Using mutate(), at a time you can create multiple columns. For example:

```
vadata = vadata %>% mutate(va3 = paste(va1,va2, sep='-'),
                           va4 = paste(va3,va2, sep='-))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following base R code, which applies to any number of columns

```
vadataout <- cbind(vadata,matrix(paste(vadata[,1],as.matrix(vadata[-1]),sep = "-"),nrow = nrow(vadata)))
```

**Example**

```
vadata <- data.frame(matrix(1:60,nrow = 2))

> vadata
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15 X16 X17 X18 X19 X20 X21 X22 X23 X24 X25 X26 X27 X28 X29 X30
1  1  3  5  7  9 11 13 15 17  19  21  23  25  27  29  31  33  35  37  39  41  43  45  47  49  51  53  55  57  59
2  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18  20  22  24  26  28  30  32  34  36  38  40  42  44  46  48  50  52  54  56  58  60
```

and you will get

```
> vadataout
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15 X16 X17 X18 X19 X20 X21 X22 X23 X24 X25 X26 X27 X28 X29 X30   1   2   3    4    5    6    7
1  1  3  5  7  9 11 13 15 17  19  21  23  25  27  29  31  33  35  37  39  41  43  45  47  49  51  53  55  57  59 1-3 1-5 1-7  1-9 1-11 1-13 1-15
2  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18  20  22  24  26  28  30  32  34  36  38  40  42  44  46  48  50  52  54  56  58  60 2-4 2-6 2-8 2-10 2-12 2-14 2-16
     8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26   27   28   29
1 1-17 1-19 1-21 1-23 1-25 1-27 1-29 1-31 1-33 1-35 1-37 1-39 1-41 1-43 1-45 1-47 1-49 1-51 1-53 1-55 1-57 1-59
2 2-18 2-20 2-22 2-24 2-26 2-28 2-30 2-32 2-34 2-36 2-38 2-40 2-42 2-44 2-46 2-48 2-50 2-52 2-54 2-56 2-58 2-60
```

Comment: how can I iterate over this though if I have 30 columns and want to create (1-2, 1-3, 1-4,...1-30)? tpying this out manually would be a mess?

Comment: @PEBguy I think you can directly apply the method in my answer, which can deal with any number of columns. See my edited example

Answer (score -2):

since I'm doing 35 categories I found iterating over a for loop through every row nrow() was the simplest and easiest solution and which works in base R.

Comment: This is not an answer. Please, insert code to make it one.